# Can you group and count in mysql on different columns?

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

Users have a list with items in different categories. 
I want to know how many items a user has in each category.

```
User    |   item  | category
____________________________
Bill    |   car   | new
Bill    |   truck | used
Bill    |   boat  | new
Bill    |   house | old
Sue     |   car   | used
Sue     |   truck | used
Bill    |   bike  | new
Sue     |   viola | used
```

I'd like the results

```
User category
__________________________
Bill|  new   |  3
Bill|  used  |  1
Bill|  sold  |  1
```

I've tried

```
$SQL = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY) FROM LIST WHERE USER=Bill";
```

but it doesn't get me very far.

Thanks

Comment: if `WHERE USER=Bill";` is your real code, it's missing quotes for `Bill`. So `WHERE USER='Bill' ";`

Comment: you could/should use aliases also.

Comment: And I feel like you could probably make a better stab at it than that

Comment: resolved first thing in the morning - sleeping works wonders. $sql="SELECT CATEGORY,
COUNT(*) 'CATEGORY_NAME_count'
FROM `LIST` WHERE USER=". $_SESSION["NUM"] ."  
GROUP BY CATEGORY
ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME_COUNT DESC
LIMIT 2";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `group by` statement:

```
select user, category, count(distinct item)
from mytable
where user = 'Bill'
group by user, category
```

Comment: thanks - got it. slightly OT -I'm new here - how do I mark that a response answered the question  - want to give credit where due

Comment: @CorneliusConboy, cool. there's a check mark under the up/downvote widget